# Installing .net web api on iis7 causes 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I installed my WebApi like it's described one this page:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/

After that i opened a Resource of the api in the browser, which causes this error:

> Http-Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> Notification MapRequestHandler
>
> Handler StaticFile

Is there possibly something I configured wrong, I wondered, why the StaticFile-Handler is used when I'm browsing a Route to an api Method

Comment: it is very difficult to provide the solution without seeing the actual code. can you share your code?

Comment: .NET Framework 4 requires you to manually register ASP.NET 4 on IIS via aspnet_regiis command.

Answer (score 0):

I usually fix the problem like this running a command: aspnet_regiis -i

See details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Comment: Sadly this didn't helped, but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, adding this line

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

to the web.config under system.webServer, solved the Problem